# Celery: how to assign some specific number of workers to different queues?

Tags: python, celery, gevent, celery-task, celeryd

I have a `celery` app consuming from large amount of queues with `gevent` concurrency.
For each queue I need to have some guaranteed number of workers, but the number is different for each queue. For example:

- qA must have 10
- qB must have 25
- qN must have M etc.

I'd like to avoid to start dedicated `celeryd` for each queue due to the large total amount of queues.

Workers do a lot of IO and I use `-P gevent` so don't care how many subworkers `celeryd` starts.

Is there a way to configure a single `celeryd` instance to assign some specific number of workers to different queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery `multi` allows to configure workers independently of each other.
For example

`celery multi start node1 node2 -c:1 5 -Q:1 queue1 -c:2 10 -Q:2 queue2`

starts 2 workers: the first `node1` consumes from `queue1` having concurrency 5, and the second `node2` consumes from `queue2` having concurrency 10.

Have a look at `multi.py` [docstring](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/bin/multi.py)